# How best to transfer a large number of arrays of chars to the GPU?

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust

I am new to CUDA and am trying to do some processing of a large number of arrays. Each array is an array of about 1000 chars (not a string, just stored as chars) and there can be up to 1 million of them, so about 1 gb of data to be transfered. This data is already all loaded into memory and I have a pointer to each array, but I don't think I can rely on all the data being sequential in memory, so I can't just transfer it all with one call.

I currently made a first go at it with thrust, and based my solution kind of on [this message](http://groups.google.com/group/thrust-users/msg/4d3cd3a6d1fc2041)  ... I made a struct with a static call that allocates all the memory, and then each individual constructor copies that array, and I have a transform call which takes in the struct with the pointer to the device array.

My problem is that this is obviously extremely slow, since each array is copied individually. I'm wondering how to transfer this data faster.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846832/memset-in-cuda-that-allows-to-set-values-within-kernel) (the question is mostly unrelated, but I think the user is trying to do something similar) talonmies suggests that they try and use a zip iterator but I don't see how that would help transfer a large number of arrays.

I also just found out about cudaMemcpy2DToArray and cudaMemcpy2D while writing this question, so maybe those are the answer, but I don't see immediately how these would work, since neither seem to take pointers to pointers as input...

Any suggestions are welcome...

Comment: If you does not need all this memory in your kernel immediately. You can copy just a part of it with synchronized copy operation and other part in asynchronous copy. Can you algorithm be adopted for this copying mechanism?

Comment: Um, i'm not sure, the algorithm works such that each array can be processed independently, which is why I'm trying to parallelize it on the GPU. I guess it depends what the maximum number of threads that are available on the GPU, and then yeah, I could just transfer that many arrays, then copy the others while those are being processed.

Comment: I ended up deciding that the best method was just to not use thrust at all, and to just re-organize the memory (meaning that I have to make a copy of it) into a contiguous array that can be transferred all at once. Thanks to those who responded.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is as marina.k suggested, batching your transfers only as you need them. Since you said each array only contains about 1000 chars, you could assign each char to a thread (since on Fermi we can allocate 1024 threads per block) and have each array handled by one block. In this case you may be able to transfer all the arrays for one "round" in one call - can you use a FORTRAN style, where you make one gigantic array and to get the 5th element of the "third" 1000 char array you would go:

```
third_array[5] = big_array[5 + 2*1000]
```

so that the first 1000 char array makes up the first 1000 elements of big_array, the second 1000 char array makes up the second 1000 elements of big_array, etc. ? In this case your chars would be continuous in memory and you could move the set you were going to process with one kernel launch in only one memcpy. Then as soon as you launch one kernel, you refill big_array on the CPU side and copy it asynchronously to the GPU.

Within each kernel, you could simply handle each array within 1 block, so that block N handles the (N-1)-thousandth element up to the N-thousandth of d_big_array (where you copied all those chars to).

Comment: Hm, I think I maybe wasn't clear enough, but the processing needs to be done on a per array basis, so I think it needs 1 thread per array. As for the 1 gigantic array, yeah, ideally I would do that, the problem is that these arrays are already loaded into memory when I do this processing and they are not loaded like that... And I don't really want to duplicate them, since it's about 1 gb of memory... but I think it looks like I may have to change the way they're loaded originally so that they are loaded as 1 large array.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try pinned memory? This may provide a considerable speed-up on some hardware configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Take try of async, you can assign the same job to different streams, each stream process a small part of date, make tranfer and computation at the same time
here is code:

```
cudaMemcpyAsync(
    inputDevPtr + i * size, hostPtr + i * size, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream[i]
);
MyKernel<<<100, 512, 0, stream[i]>>> (outputDevPtr + i * size, inputDevPtr + i * size, size);
cudaMemcpyAsync(
    hostPtr + i * size, outputDevPtr + i * size, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream[i]
);
```